# spring boot web client and writing pact contracts

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient, pact

So im trying to figure out how to write consumer contracts for the following class. I have written junit tests fine using mockwebserver.
However for pact testing im struggling and cant seem to see how you get the weblient to use the response from server, all the examples tend to be for resttemplate.

```
public class OrdersGateway {

    public static final String PATH = "/orders";
    private final WebClient webClient;

    @Autowired
    public OrdersGateway(String baseURL) {

        this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public Orderresponse findOrders() {
        return this.webClient
                .post()
                .uri(PATH)
                .httpRequest(httpRequest -> {
                    HttpClientRequest reactorRequest = httpRequest.getNativeRequest();
                    reactorRequest.responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(4));
                })
                .exchangeToMono(response())
                .block();
    }

    private Function<ClientResponse, Mono<OrderResponse>> response() {
        return result -> {
                if (result.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                    return result.bodyToMono(OrderResponse.class);
                } else {
                    String exception = String.format("error", result.statusCode());
                    return Mono.error(new IllegalStateException(exception));
                }
            };
    }

  
}
```

Its the @test method for verification, im not sure how to create that. I cant see how the pact-mock-server can intercept the webcleint call.

Answer (score -1):

There might be an assumption that Pact automatically intercepts requests - this is not the case.

So when you write a Pact unit test, you need to explicitly configure your API client to communicate to the Pact mock service, not the real thing.

Using this [example](https://github.com/pactflow/example-consumer-java-junit/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/products/ProductsPactTest.java#L44-L50) as a basis, your test might look like this:

```
@ExtendWith(PactConsumerTestExt.class)
@PactTestFor(providerName = "orders-gateway")
public class OrdersPactTest {

  @Pact(consumer="orders-provider")
  public RequestResponsePact findOrders(PactDslWithProvider builder) {

    PactDslJsonBody body = PactDslJsonArray.arrayEachLike()
      .uuid("id", "5cc989d0-d800-434c-b4bb-b1268499e850")
      .stringType("status", "STATUS")
      .decimalType("amount", 100.0)
      .closeObject();

      return builder
        .given("orders exist")
        .uponReceiving("a request to find orders")
          .path("/orders")
          .method("GET")
        .willRespondWith()
          .status(200)
          .body(body)
        .toPact();
    }

  @PactTestFor(pactMethod = "findOrders")
  @Test
  public void findOrders(MockServer mockServer) throws IOException {
    OrdersGateway orders = new OrdersGateway(mockServer.getUrl()).findOrders();
    
    // do some assertions
  }
}
```